# Can dbms_output buffer over flow exception be overridden by statement handle not executed exception?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If Proc 1 throws **ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow**, **limit of `20000 bytes error`** and another procedure proc 2 has a `dbms_output stement` as first line of code and it has a sys_refcursor as an out param , will the second proc throw "`statement not handled exception`" or "`buffer over flow exception`" ?

Proc 2 has not set any select statement to curosr in exception block . also , there are lots of calls from web service to both these procs simultaneously from mutiple machines .

Comment: Do you think some one will help you based on this? Think about the third person who has to imagine your DB and code with your para. Please elaborate and provide more information. Post code wherever applicable.

Comment: procedure proc_1 (a varchar ) begin dbms_output.put_line('this output is reapedted mutiple times')  dbms_output.put_line('this output is reapedted mutiple times') -- this output is put mutiple times end proc_1; IN MY WEBSERVICE LOGS (WHICH CALLS THIS PROC) I CAN see buffer over flow exceptions for proc 1 . <br\> another proc proc 2 is also throwing exceptiosn when called from same web service exception being statement handle not execued . CODE : procedure proc_2 (cur out sys_refcursor) begin dbms_out_putline("1") ; open cur for select * from users ; exception when others then raise end;

Comment: should the proc 2 raise buffer over flow exception as its first statement is dbms out putline / should it through statement handle not executed as sys ref cursor is not assigned a select statement in exception block . Please let me if any other info is required

Comment: Please edit your question to add new information, particularly code (and [format the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)); don't dump lots of text into comments where it's hard to read.

Comment: Try to increase your output buffer for starters. You can use unlimited buffer from Oracle 10g.

Comment: i know the buffer can be increased but this issue happened at client location when many users were trying to access these procs through web services . but instead of the buffer overflow exception the second proc threw statement handle not executed exception.

Comment: It's still really, really unclear quite what you're doing and seeing, but it looks like it might be an issue with how you're calling this. Are you checking for an error from the call before trying to refer to the ref cursor, which won't have been initialised? If the exception block catches the buffer overflow and then tries to output its own message that will raise its own exception and not complete your handling; in your example `out_error_code` would not be set. So you'd have to be looking for a raised error, not just checking the `out_error_code` is not null, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test
(
 IN_ATTUID in VARCHAR2,  
  OUT_USER_DETAILS out SYS_REFCURSOR,  
  OUT_ERROR_CODE out NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
   tmpVar := 0;
   dbms_output.enable(2000);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('PUT a 2000 BYTE CHARACTER HERE');

dbms_output.put_line('1');

  OUT_ERROR_CODE := NULL;      

   open OUT_USER_DETAILS for select * from t_roles;


  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('OUT_ERROR_CODE' || OUT_ERROR_CODE);
  commit;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise

       DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('OUT_ERROR_CODE' || OUT_ERROR_CODE);
   --OUT_ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('OUT_ERROR_CODE' || SQLCODE);

       DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('OUT_ERROR_CODE' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 800));
       --RAISE;

END proc_test;
```

STATEMENT HANDLE NOT EECUTED EXCEPTION IS THROWN TO WEB SERVICE WHEN A PROC OVERFLOWS THE DBMS BUFFER AND HAS AN SYS REFCURSOR AS OUT PARAMETER INSTEAD OF BUFFER OVERFLOW EXCEPTION. 
GIVEN ABOVE IS A SMALL TEST TO REACH TO THIS CONCLUSION.

Comment: sorry alex i dint realise caps lock is on . I have answered the question in the answer . It is not a part of the question . Please read it agian .sorry again for the caps .

Comment: I'm not sure it does answer it, it maybe shows part of how to replicate it, though this doesn't compile as it is and you haven't shown how to call it to get that error. It doesn't explain why - which I think is down to the `dbms_output` inside the exception handler. Still, as long as you've answered it to your own satisfaction I suppose...